# Rename existing rails model and add namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Original code looks like this:

```
# app/models/sso_configuration.rb
class SsoConfiguration < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# db/schema.rb
create_table "sso_configurations", force: true do |t|
  ...
end
```

I have to rename the model and add namespace so that I'll have `Sso::SamlConfiguration`. I changed model and database table.

```
# db/migrate20160225144615_rename_sso_configurations_to_sso_saml_configurations.rb
class RenameSsoConfigurationsToSsoSamlConfigurations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :sso_configurations, :sso_saml_configurations
  end
end

# db/schema.rb
create_table "sso_saml_configurations", force: true do |t|
  ...
end

# app/models/sso/saml_configuration.rb
module Sso
  class SamlConfiguration < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

When I open my rails console, the following happens.

```
> Sso::SamlConfiguration
=> Sso::SamlConfiguration(Table doesn't exist)
> Sso::SamlConfiguration.new
=> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "saml_configurations" does not exist
```

My original thinking was that namespaced models should, by convention, have the snakecase name as the table name such that `Foo::Bar` should have a corresponding `foo_bars` table. Am I missing something with my setup?

Comment: I took a look at namespacing the model name, `class Sso::SamlConfiguration < ActiveRecord.base`, and used the `self.table_name = '[your table name]'`. Not sure if that would fit your situation. I have heard (although can't seem to find any articles about) that models in modules isn't really supported in Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution by copying what rails would do if I let it generate a namespaced model for me

```
rails g model sso/test

invoke  active_record
create    db/migrate/20160226074853_create_sso_tests.rb
create    app/models/sso/test.rb
create    app/models/sso.rb
invoke    rspec
create      spec/models/sso/test_spec.rb
invoke      factory_girl
create        spec/factories/sso_tests.rb
```

I checked all the path and name conventions in these new files and the only one I missed was the file `app/models/sso.rb`.

Creating the following solved my problem:

```
# app/models/sso.rb
module Sso
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'sso_'
  end
end
```

Then

```
rails d model sso/test
```

Answer (score 1):

> rename_table :sso_configurations, :sso_saml_configurations

would imply this `SsoSamlConfiguration.all` when your trying to do this `Sso::SamlConfiguration.all`

Simply rollback your migration and change this line

```
rename_table :sso_configurations, :sso_saml_configurations
```

to this

```
rename_table :sso_configurations, :saml_configurations
```

and now this should work

```
Sso::SamlConfiguration.all
```

Answer (score 0):

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "saml_configurations" does not
>   exist

Rails by default looks for the table whose name is **plural name** of model i.e, in your case it looks for `saml_configurations` as the model name is `saml_configuration`.

You need to explicitly map the model to a different table by using `self.table_name`

```
# app/models/sso/saml_configuration.rb
module Sso
  class SamlConfiguration < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "sso_saml_configurations"
  end
end
```